# How to enable text selection in WebBrowser Control C#

Tags: c#, text, browser, selection

I am building a simpel ePub reader using the WebBrowser Control and i have the files HTML markup loading into the control fine. The problem is the user is unable to select text using the mouse. Right click and select all works but the user will need to be able to highlight/copy/paste which will require the usual method of selecting with the mouse..

I am surprised this is not standard behaviour which leads me to think i may be doing something wrong. Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: I just tried and it works without any problems.